# React Router Access Control

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a route that is using regex to dynamically generate a view with React.

```
<Route path='/(one|two|three)/' component={View} />
```

I want to do some access control so that only specific users are able to access the various endpoints. It would look like "You are part of a group that allows access to view 1, but view 2 and 3 are denied".

Is this possible in a route defined like this? Would it be easier to separately define the routes and then define authorization?

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with making a `PrivateRoute` or `AuthenticatedRoute` component that checks permissions and then decides whether to render some component or redirect to the login page, or some other appropriate page.

Here's a full [tutorial](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/).

One complexity that the tutorial does not cover is that you don't want to check *just* if the user is logged in, but also what permissions they have and do their permissions satisfy the conditions for the route. You can define that however you'd like. You could require the user have at least 1 out of a list of permissions, you could require that they have all of a list of permissions.

For your case, I would just have 3 `PrivateRoute`s like such:

```
<PrivateRoute path='/one' component={View1} permissionsRequired={["View1Permission"]}/> 
<PrivateRoute path='/two' component={View2} permissionsRequired={["View2Permission"]}/> 
<PrivateRoute path='/three' component={View3} permissionsRequired={["View3Permission"]}/>
```

And if a user goes to one of the routes, the `PrivateRoute` will check if they have permission, and if they do, then render the `View` and if not, then redirect to some appropriate page that they do have access to.